# Managing bower dependencies with ionic

Tags: bower, ionic-framework, bower-install

After starting with a new ionic app, I can see at `bower.json` that comes with ionic is in `devdependencies`. Why is it a `devdependency` and not a normal `dependency`?

```
"devDependencies": {
    "ionic": "driftyco/ionic-bower#1.0.0-rc.0"
},
```

Thanks, I feel confused right now

Comment: Wondering exactly the same thing myself

Answer (score 2):

having **devDependencies** gives you the opportunity to simplify the steps that drive you from the source files (a git clone of the project) to the production ready app

when you don't need to make changes and (develop) the application, you could just run

```
bower install --production
```

or

```
npm install --production
```

they work the same

## bower install options

> ```
> -F, --force-latest: Force latest version on conflict
>
> -p, --production: Do not install project devDependencies
>
> -S, --save: Save installed packages into the project’s bower.json dependencies
>
> -D, --save-dev: Save installed packages into the project’s bower.json devDependencies
>
> -E, --save-exact: Configure installed packages with an exact version rather than semver
> ```

[bower documentation](http://bower.io/docs/api/#install)

## npm  install options

> By default, npm install will install all modules listed as
>   dependencies. With the --production flag (or when the NODE_ENV
>   environment variable is set to production), npm will not install
>   modules listed in devDependencies.
>   [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

This way you take less time to ship the app and don't waste bandwidth downloading stuff you won't need.

Given that, to me, the choice of listing ionic as devDependecy is a poor one: it implies that I could take advantage of this choice to get ready the app for execution this way:

```
git clone my-project
git cd my-project
npm install --production # ionic not installed here
ionic state restore
ionic build ios
```

Now, if you ignore the content of /lib folder in your sources, this should not work, and if it works because the ionic-cli does some more checks to save your ass, I think this is unclear.

Comment: Isn't ionic required for production, since index.html references files in lib/ionic?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, `dependencies` are required to run, and `devDependencies` are only for development, like minification, unit tests, etc.

Both will install when you do `npm install` but only `dependencies` will install when you do `npm install $package`, unless you add the `--dev` option

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ok, thats the difference between a `dependency` and a `devdependency`. But my question is why ionic is a `devdependency`.

Comment: @cor I think they consider ionic and all bower packages as devdependency, because the final production for ionic is the IOS app