# Ionic android/ios www to apk process

Tags: android, ios, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I converted my website into an ionic app and its almost 15MB. I have put all my JS ,HTML, and CSS files into the www/app directory. Bower components are inside www/lib. I use gulp to concatenate all my .js and .css files and put them inside www/js and www/css folders respectively. I want to reduce the size of the apk. Right now my source files and libraries are inside www. I wanted to know whether ionic just compiles the www into apk or does it take the entire project folder and turn it into an apk. I am thinking to move all my source files somewhere outside the directory and then use gulp to concatenate and store in www. I am also thinking of deleting unnecessary bower files.
 Will that reduce the size of the apk? Are there any other practices I should follow to reduce the size.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To build an apk use `ionic build android`

for reducing apk size check this [link](https://medium.com/@b.sandesh/how-to-reduce-ionic-app-size-b0dd71ae3cd5#.do576pfhc) out.

Hope it helps.

Comment: how about the bower files inside lib? should i remove the unnecessary files?

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31760448/6799753) for clarification.